# How can I find out if the current user is in a specific group?

Tags: users, group

If I type `groups` I get a list a back,

```
$> groups
ecarroll cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth docker
```

How can I find out if the logged in user is in a specific group?

Comment: Do you want to know if a *user* is in a group or a *process* is in a group (like your usage of the `groups` command suggests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use

```
groups | grep -E '(^| )mygroup($| )'
```

Comment: Note that it checks the credentials of the current process, not that of a given user. It will also give false negatives if `mygroup` shares the same gid as `myothergroup` and `getgrgid()` return `myothergroup` instead of `mygroup` for that gid.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find that the current process has one of its real gid, effective gid or any supplementary gid matching that of a given group name, on a GNU system, you could do:

```
if
  gid=$(set -o pipefail; getent -- group "$group" | cut -d: -f3) &&
    id -G | grep -qwe "$gid"
then
  printf '%s\n' "current process credentials include $group's id ($gid)"
fi
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -se 'if (@g = getgrnam($group)) {
            for (split " ", $)) {exit if $_ == $g[2]}
          }
          exit 1' -- -group="$group"
```

To check that a given `$user` is listed as a member of a given group, or that their primary gid matches the id of `$group`, you'd do the same but with `id -G -- "$user"` instead of `id -G`, but it may say that `$user` is member of `$group` even if they're not listed as one of its members if they happen to be member of another group with the same gid.

Remember that in the `passwd` and `group` databases, the *key* is the user/group name, not id and that several users/groups can have the same id. So approaches that work first by converting id to name and comparing are wrong in the general case (though these days, it's rare for several users to share the same uid and even rarer for several groups to share the same gid).